# Unable to start a test app on an emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have these configurations to the AVD:

[image]

and Installed the min SDK API 10

[image]

and the application manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is just a test application, just created.

So, when i run the application, it tries to run on the above AVD, and gives these errors on the emulator:

```
The application Package Access Helper(process.com.android.defcontainer) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again
```

and many more such errors saying:

**sdksetup stopped working**

**clock stopped working**

....
....

**LogCat:**

```
12-24 14:25:12.089: I/dalvikvm(405): Unable to open or create cache for /system/app/Phone.apk (/data/dalvik-cache/system@app@Phone.apk@classes.dex)
12-24 14:25:12.169: D/AndroidRuntime(405): Shutting down VM
12-24 14:25:12.169: W/dalvikvm(405): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.phone.PhoneApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.phone.PhoneApp in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/app/Phone.apk]
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:466)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3260)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.phone.PhoneApp in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/app/Phone.apk]
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)
12-24 14:25:12.189: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  ... 11 more
12-24 14:25:12.289: W/ActivityManager(70): Process com.android.phone has crashed too many times: killing!
12-24 14:25:12.330: W/DropBoxManagerService(70): Dropping: system_app_crash (1630 > 0 bytes)
12-24 14:25:12.509: W/ActivityManager(70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{408f4388 com.android.sdksetup/.DefaultActivity}
12-24 14:25:12.729: I/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.sdksetup/.DefaultActivity } from pid 0
12-24 14:25:13.079: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_CONCURRENT freed 480K, 54% free 2696K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 6ms+57ms
12-24 14:25:13.962: W/ActivityManager(70): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
12-24 14:25:21.707: W/ActivityManager(70): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{408f4388 com.android.sdksetup/.DefaultActivity}
12-24 14:25:22.843: W/ActivityManager(70): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{406d47a0 com.android.sdksetup/.DefaultActivity}
12-24 14:25:27.899: D/skia(70): purging 45K from font cache [6 entries]
12-24 14:25:28.029: D/dalvikvm(70): GC_EXPLICIT freed 415K, 56% free 4455K/9991K, external 1492K/1828K, paused 135ms
12-24 14:25:31.741: W/ActivityManager(70): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{408f4388 com.android.sdksetup/.DefaultActivity}
12-24 14:25:33.209: D/dalvikvm(296): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 55% free 2583K/5703K, external 716K/1038K, paused 132ms
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

how to resolve this?

Thank You

Comment: please add your logcat and your code

Comment: Delete your emulator and recreate it from scratch.

Comment: @Blundell yep, tried that a lot of times. That's why posted the config, just in case i am doing something wrong :(

Comment: Well `ClassNotFoundException: com.android.phone.PhoneApp` means your emulator / android sdk is screwed. If you really want to fix it, I would delete your android SDK and just start again

Comment: Fine. will try re-installing the SDK

Comment: @Blundell instead can i just update the **Android SDK Tools** and **Android SDK Platform-tools** from **Android SDK Manager**??

Comment: Hi @archie could you please explain it brief...so it will be easy to solve the issue..!!!